# Google API 400 with no details

Tags: google-api

I'm trying to call the Google Calendar API, Insert Event, and the error I get back has no useful information:

```json
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I'm trying it from the API explorer itself. Here is my request body:

```json
POST https://content.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/ev8pf9pxxxxxx%40group.calendar.google.com/events?alt=json&key=AIzaSyAa8yy0GdcGPHdtD083HiGGx_xxxxx

{
  summary: 'APPTEST Gig',
  location: 'The Barn at Gibbet Hill, Groton, MA',
  description:
    'Ceremony, 5:30-6:00: Jonathan (Keys), Fransisco (Audio)\nCocktail Hour, 6:00-7:00: Jonathan (Keys)',
  start: { dateTime: 'Sat, 15 Feb 2025 22:00:00 GMT' },
  end: { dateTime: 'Sun, 16 Feb 2025 04:00:00 GMT' },
}
```

I'd really love to know why I'm not getting any actual error information! But if you know why my payload is wrong that's good too I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for the dates is wrong

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[CALENDARID]/events?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"end":{"dateTime":"2013-11-22T08:35:00+01:00"},"start":{"dateTime":"2013-11-22T08:35:00+01:00"}}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: Thanks, I did figure this out. I just wish it would have told me in the response!